# Applying select2 on dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a block of HTML that I am cloning when a specific link is clicked -- it allows the user to select multiple products to add to their order.

Within each row there is a select box that has a class `select2`, this enables the `select2` plugin on the field.

```
<div class="form-group product">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <select name="sku[]" class="form-control select2"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click to clone the above HTML then the second row doesn't have an active `select2`.

```
$('.select2').select2();

$('.new-product').click(function() {
    $( ".product:first" ).clone().appendTo( ".products" );
    return false;
});
```

I have tried adding the `$('.select2').select2();` before `return false` but this doesn't seem to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.new-product').click(function() {
    var clone = $( ".product:first" ).clone();
    $(".products").append(clone);
    clone.find('.select2').select2();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: No luck, unfortunately

Comment: This seems to break the select2 on the first instance, it also creates two select boxes in the second instance and one of them has select2